# Lp space contained in the intersection of Lq, where 1≤q≤p.

Tags: measure-theory, lp-spaces

Let $(X, \Sigma, \mu)$ be a measure space with $\mu$(X) $< \infty$.
Let $p \in [1,\infty)$.

I would like to prove that $L^p \subseteq \underset{1 \leq q \leq p}\cap L^q$.
I'm not sure how to go about this question, so would appreciate any help. Thanks!